# c++ Passing double values between 3d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two problems.

First, I show my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

int pom1_1 = 28;
int pom2_1 = 0;
int pom3_1 = 1;

double ***observace_r = new double **[28];
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    observace_r[i] = new double *[40];

    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)                    
        observace_r[i][j] = new double [3];     
}

observace_r[pom1_1][pom2_1][pom3_1] = 100;      //THERE IS THE PROBLEM NO.1

double ***dif_observace_ref = new double **[28];
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
    dif_observace_ref[i] = new double *[40];

    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)                    
        dif_observace_ref[i][j] = new double [3];       
}

dif_observace_ref[i][j][k] = observace_r[pom1_1][pom2_1][pom3_1];  //THERE IS THE PROBLEM NO.2

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

***My problems:***

*The first one:* I don´t know how to assign a double value to element of 3d array. If I try it like in this code, program crashes. But if I would write it like this:

```
observace_r[0][0][0] = 100;
```

program would be executed. Why is it working in this way?

*The second one:* If I pass a double value between two elements of 3d arrays, it will crash too. Why I would pass this value?

Thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second problems, are that index `28` is actually out of array bounds and you are trying to dereference invalid pointer.

```
observace_r[pom1_1][pom2_1][pom3_1] = 100; // pom1_1 = 28
```

Comment: One question remains: If array bounds for array "observace_r" will be for example 1000 (all of them) and array bounds for "dif_observace_ref" will be the same as in the code above, will it work? (I mean problem no.2)

Comment: @mrkvator This code will work while indices are in bounds. So just don't try to access to element that was not allocated.